# Make ffmpeg reference position coordinates?

Tags: ffmpeg

let's say I have the following ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf  "drawtext=text='hello world':x=100:y=100" output.mp4
```

But I need the text position to follow an array/list of position data (x, y) like so:

```
100, 100
101, 103
102, 106
103, 109
and so on...
```

How could I make ffmpeg reference the list of `x, y` coordinates on every frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't directly possible.

But you could create a text file containing multiple `drawtext` filters and then feed that as a `filter_script`.

e.g.

```
drawtext=text='hello world':x=100:y=100:enable='eq(n\,0)',
drawtext=text='hello world':x=101:y=103:enable='eq(n\,1)',
drawtext=text='hello world':x=102:y=106:enable='eq(n\,2)',
drawtext=text='hello world':x=103:y=109:enable='eq(n\,3)'
```

And then run

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_script:v file.txt out.mp4
```

---

Although I see from your sequence of numbers that this looks to be a linear interpolation of values. If you're doing a smooth animation of the text position, then you can supply an expression for `x` and `y` and skip/contract the textfile.

Comment: Thank you! I suppose this could also be done this way without the external text file, just inline with the command.

Comment: That's right. ....